# TypeError, 'digest' of undefined, in development environment

Tags: auth0

When we're building our Angular SPA for localhost it works perfectly.

On our dev environment, this error creeps into the DevTool console and breaks everything:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'digest' of undefined

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'digest' of undefined
    at N (auth0-spa-js.production.js:1)
    at ie.<anonymous> (auth0-spa-js.production.js:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at auth0-spa-js.production.js:1
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:876)
    at t (auth0-spa-js.production.js:1)
    at ie.loginWithRedirect (auth0-spa-js.production.js:1)
    at AuthGuard.<anonymous> (auth.guard.ts:22)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (environment.ts:11)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:879)
    at t (auth0-spa-js.production.js:1)
    at ie.loginWithRedirect (auth0-spa-js.production.js:1)
    at AuthGuard.<anonymous> (auth.guard.ts:22)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (environment.ts:11)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:34195)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
```

I guess it must be something about the build process, some different flags, but I can't figure out exactly which.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's probably because your dev server is setup as an insecure origin.

The `digest` likely refers to `window.crypto.subtle.digest` of the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API). if you are using a Chromium-based browser, according to the the [Chromium Projects page here](https://www.chromium.org/blink/webcrypto), the `subtle` property can only be used in a secure origin:

> Access to the WebCrypto API is restricted to secure origins (which is to say https:// pages).
>
> Note: In the spec, crypto.subtle is supposed to be undefined in insecure contexts

Because `digest` is a method of `subtle`, and `subtle` is `undefined`, you are getting this error.

We got the same error when using the [auth0-spa-js library](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js). It worked on localhost, not on our http staging site, but OK on our production https site.

If you aren't in a secure origin, try making your dev environment secure and then testing again (a self-signed certificate should do). As a reminder, [secure origins](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/security-faq#TOC-Which-origins-are-secure-) are:

> ### Which origins are "secure"?
>
> Secure origins are those that match at least one of the following (scheme, host, port) patterns:
>
> - (https, *, *)
> - (wss, *, *)
> - (*, localhost, *)
> - (*, 127/8, *)
> - (*, ::1/128, *)
> - (file, *, —)
> - (chrome-extension, *, —)
>
> That is, secure origins are those that load resources either from the local machine (necessarily trusted) or over the network from a cryptographically-authenticated server.

I'm not sure if the [Auth0](https://auth0.com) team have an SPA library that works in a non-secure origin (or plans to enable that capability in their latest SPA library), but their native JS libraries definitely do.

Comment: What if I'm using ionic://localhost in my app? I'm facing the same error, and because of [Firebase Auth with Cordova](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova) I cannot change this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Angular framework:
Getting an HTTPS by configuring a SSL certificate to your application's nginx (nginx.conf or app.conf) solves this problem.
Assign a ssl certificate and ssl key for your domain. Make sure to change your port to 443.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -2):

This seems more related to Angular than Auth0 but out of curiosity have you defined `digest` in your component?

If not, you can do that as: `digest: {};` at the component level.

I hope this helps you on your quest!