# How to tell Firefox to trust "xxx.localhost" as a secure origin?

Tags: firefox, auth0

In the last week or so (approximately same timeframe as Firefox 75 release), local development of my example application ([Rabbit](https://bitbucket.org/kopi-cloud/rabbit/)) that uses `auth0-spa-js` has started failing in Firefox with the below error:

```
auth0-spa-js must run on a secure origin.
  See https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-do-i-get-auth0-spa-js-must-run-on-a-secure-origin 
  for more information.
```

Because of some problem I can't quite remember the details of, I've been using `rabbit.localhost` (with an entry in my `hosts` to resolve that host to `127.0.0.1`) for my local development.

It seems that Firefox trusts "localhost" as a "secure origin", but not "*.localhost" type addresses.  The ".localhost" address seems to work fine in Chrome.

The question:
Is there a way to get Firefox to accept a specific "xxx.localhost" as a secure origin?

For the moment, my workaround is to go back to using Chrome for local development.

Comment: I found two related questions : https://stackoverflow.com/q/57146558 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/61867895, but there doesn’t seem to be an easy solution at the moment. The second question has a link to an open [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220810) in Firefox about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed in version 84:
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25431563