# Unsecure Origin (Heroku App) renders NodeJS's Web Cryptography API require() undefined. Is there any workaround?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to implement the experimental Web cryptography api (subtlecrypto) on my Herokuapp Nodejs server so as to encrypt the data from a gitpages -> herokuapp fetch request, hiding the sensible information within from the browser console network tab to then decrypt client-side.

I'm following https://www.nearform.com/blog/implementing-the-web-cryptography-api-for-node-js-core/ as a reference.

Unfortunately, any method that I try to call from subtlecrypto comes back as undefined, spouting errors such as

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'encrypt' of undefined
```

when I try to run

```
const cipher = await SubtleCrypto.encrypt({ name: 'AES-CBC', iv }, ckey, ec.encode('data'));
```

Or

```
ReferenceError: getRandomValues is not defined
```

when I try to define

```
const iv = getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
```

The [TypeError, 'digest' of undefined, in development environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146558/typeerror-digest-of-undefined-in-development-environment) thread seems to pinpoint the issue (chromium deems origin as unsecure, prohibiting subtlecrypto use), but fails to provide a solution for my own environment.

### Here's my pipeline:

In github pages (Enforce HTTPS enabled), this .js file is linked in an html page, sending a fetch request to my Heroku App

```js
var apikey, dir, documentdir;

function makeid(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));}return result;
}

var tag=makeid(32);

document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function () {
    fetch("https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/NotTheActualLink", {headers: {"header1" : tag, "header2" : aString}} )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
                "raw", //can be "jwk" or "raw"
                {   //this is an example jwk key, "raw" would be an ArrayBuffer
                    kty: "oct",
                    k: tag,
                    alg: "A256CBC",
                    ext: true,
                },
                {   //this is the algorithm options
                    name: "AES-CBC",
                },
                false, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
                ["encrypt", "decrypt"] //can be "encrypt", "decrypt", "wrapKey", or "unwrapKey"
            )
            .then(function(key){
                window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
                    {
                        name: "AES-CBC",
                        iv: data.vi, //The initialization vector you used to encrypt
                    },
                    key, //from generateKey or importKey above
                    data.iv //ArrayBuffer of the data
                )
                .then(function(decrypted){
                    //returns an ArrayBuffer containing the decrypted data
                    console.log(new Uint8Array(decrypted));
    
                    apikey = data.api;
                    doccy = data.docname;
                    dir = data.dir;
                })
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });
        })
        .then(function () {
            var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({ clientId: apikey, divId: "adobe-dc-view" });
            adobeDCView.previewFile({
                content: { location: { url: dir } },
                metaData: { fileName: doccy }
            }, { embedMode: "IN_LINE", showDownloadPDF: false, showPrintPDF: false });
        });
});
```

When the app detects a request to api/NotTheActualLink, it reads the custom headers I sent it so as to get both the random string for generating the cryptographic key (ckey) and the ID of the document that I want it to respond with (id).

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const SubtleCrypto = require("crypto").webcrypto;

const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const origin = process.env.ORIGIN_URL;
const db = process.env.DB_NAME;
const col = process.env.COL_NAME;
const path = process.env.API_PATH;
const xheader1 = process.env.X_HEADER_1;
const xheader2 = process.env.X_HEADER_2;

app.options(path, async function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', xheader1.concat(", ",xheader2));
  next();
});

app.get(path, async function (req, res) {
  const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', xheader1.concat(", ",xheader2));

  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log("isSecureContext= "+app.isSecureContext);
    var ckey = req.header(xheader1);
    var id = req.header(xheader2);
    console.log("key= "+ckey);
    console.log("id= "+id);

    const database = client.db(db);
    const collection = database.collection(col);
    const query = { docId: id };
    const cursor = await collection.findOne(query);
    const result = cursor;

    const ec = new TextEncoder();
    const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
    const iv = getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
    const cipher = await SubtleCrypto.encrypt({ name: 'AES-CBC', iv }, ckey, ec.encode(result));
    const data = await SubtleCrypto.encrypt({ name: 'AES-CBC', iv }, ckey, cipher);
  
    var response =
    {
      iv: iv.toString('hex'),
      dater: data.toString('hex')
    };

    return res.json(response);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  finally {
    await client.close();
  }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,
  () => console.log("Server is running..."));
```

From there it establishes connection to my MongoDB cluster (link: mongodb+srv://yada:yadayada@foo.bar.mongodb.net/mydatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority) and retrieves the document with the data that I want to encrypt and sends to the client browser. Or at least that's what it was supposed to be doing.

I just can't understand which of these interactions makes the connection insecure, disabling subtlecrypto.

### What can I do to make the origin secure?

Also, `console.log("isSecureContext= "+app.isSecureContext);` doesn't seem to target the origin, but window.isSecureContext does not work either because the app (it's just the above .js file) isn't running in a browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had help from a friend with this one, but I got it!
The origin was secure, it was never a problem to begin with. The server's Nodejs version was indeed the problem.

### WebCrypto was only added in node v15.x, since Heroku was running the LTS version (14.5.5) all it took was an update!

Check this guide for further details:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version